# Distributions with some conditions

Tags: distributions, cumulative-distribution-function

Suppose $F(x)$ and $G(x)$ are some CDF's with support $[0,1]$. I'm looking for relationship between $F$ and $G$ when it satisfies those following conditions:
$$G^{-1}\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)\int^1_0F(x)(1-F(x))dx=\int^1_0xF(x)(1-F(x))dx$$ and
$$F^{-1}\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)\int^1_0G(x)(1-G(x))dx=\int^1_0xG(x)(1-G(x))dx$$

What kind of relationship should $F$ and $G$ have to satisfy those conditions?

For example, if $F$ and $G$ are CDF's of uniform$[0,1$], they satisfy the conditions. What would be more general sufficient conditions?

Comment: In the case of the uniform each side of the equations equals 1/12.

Comment: Please don't post the same question on two different sites: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2350097/171839

Comment: For F=G=$x^n$ you just need to find the values of n that satisfy the first relationship.  This appears to be the case only when n=1 (i.e. the uniform case).For the beta family of distributions there may be values for the parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ that satisfy the first relationship with F=G.

Comment: @TheIncredibleZ1 Oh, okay. I didn't know I'm not allowed to do that. I just deleted the question on math stackexchange.

Comment: @Michael Chernick Thank you for your suggestion! I'll try beta distributions.

Comment: The _support_ of a CDF must necessarily extend to $\infty$ since a CDF approaches (or has already attained) the value $1$ as its argument tends to $\infty$.  I think what you mean is that with probability $1$, the random variables take values in the unit interval.